# Nested shallow resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I'm wondering if I'm making the routes file correctly for a new application.

In it I have the following Models:

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :employer
 has_many :dependents
 has_many :identities, as: :person
end

class Dependent < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :member
 has_many :identities, as: :person
end

class Identity < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :person, polymorphic: true
end
```

My route file I've made so far is:

```
resources :members, shallow: true do
  resources :identities
  resources :dependents, shallow: true do
    resources :identities
  end
end
```

Am I doing this as one would think makes sense, or completely off base as normal ;-) Thanks for any help in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was working as I hoped. the nested shallow must pull the dependents out as hoped.